# Retrieve the latitude and longitude of a place given its name

Tags: python, geolocation

What is the best method (which does not require an API key) to obtain the coordinates (latitude and longitude) of a place given its name (not its address)? Right now I am using

```
import requests
import urllib.parse

university = 'Universität Wien'
url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/' + urllib.parse.quote(university) + '?format=json'

response = requests.get(url).json()
print(response[0]['lat'])
print(response[0]['lon'])
```

Are there other ways? I have to find the coordinates of some universities given their name.

Comment: What is wrong with this code? Seems like you are asking for alternative API endpoints (or a list of pre-defined coordinates you can download). Both would be asking for off-site resources, thus off topic as per [help].

Comment: For example if I try to search for 'EPHE - ECOLE PRATIQUE DES HAUTES ETUDES' it returns an error, but if I search for that name in Google Maps it gives me a precise position.

Comment: What is the error? OpenStreetMap doesn't necessarily have the same results as Google Search/Maps

Comment: So there is no way to improve results without using API key. Thanks for the info.

Comment: The purpose of using API keys is usage tracking or offering better results for a cost, usually. Otherwise, the servers do other ways of rate limiting.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `geopy.geocoders` library instead of calling API

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises")
university = 'Universität Wien'
address=geolocator.geocode(university)
print(address.latitude ,address.longitude)
```